# jprofiler trial version is not allowing multiple clients to connect to the server

Tags: jprofiler

I am trying to connect to a jprofiler server running on linux 64 machile, from windows xp,
It connects for the first client, but when I try to connect from another windows client to that server it just keeps trying to connect , but never succeeds.
please let me know how I can enable the jprofiler sever allow multiple client connections.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that is not possible. The profiling agent in JProfiler only works in a one-to-one connection mode.